# SimpleFlatMapper: Multiple 1-N relationship

Tags: java, jpa, jooq, jdbctemplate

Please refer this link:

https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/jooq/jooq-tips-implementing-a-read-only-one-to-many-relationship/#comment-1966747

import java.util.List;

```
public class StudentDTO {
 
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<BookDTO> books;
 
    //Getters and setters are omitted
}
```

here there is one 1-N relationship books which needs to be extracted.
That is achieved through addKeys.

But let us say if the POJO is:

```
public class StudentDTO {
 
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<BookDTO> books;
    private List<CourseDTO> courses;
    //Getters and setters are omitted
}
```

then how can we achieve it?

Comment: one of the solution is to have a customer mapper. I am not sure how to achieve it too. Not sure about it.

Comment: Also, I do not want to do multiple queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you chose to use SimpleFlatMapper because that article recommended it. But jOOQ has a much better out of the box way to map to-many relationship, see the [`MULTISET` operator](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/multiset-value-constructor/).

Assuming you have a constructor for your attributes, or even use a `record` type:

```java
public record StudentDTO(
    Long id,
    String name,
    List<BookDTO> books,
    List<CourseDTO> courses
{}
```

You can now write a query like this:

```java
List<StudentDTO> students =
ctx.select(
       STUDENT.ID,
       STUDENT.NAME,
       multiset(
           select(STUDENT_BOOK.book().ID, ...)
           .from(STUDENT_BOOK)
           .where(STUDENT_BOOK.STUDENT_ID.eq(STUDENT.ID))
       ).convertFrom(r -> r.map(Records.mapping(BookDTO::new))),
       multiset(
           select(STUDENT_COURSE.course().ID, ...)
           .from(STUDENT_COURSE)
           .where(STUDENT_COURSE.STUDENT_ID.eq(STUDENT.ID))
       ).convertFrom(r -> r.map(Records.mapping(CourseDTO::new)))
   )
   .from(STUDENT)
   .fetch(Records.mapping(StudentDTO::new));
```

The [ad-hoc conversion feature](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/fetching/ad-hoc-converter/) makes the whole thing type safe.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. Yes, this should have solved the issue. But due to some reason I cannot use JOOQ. I can just use SimpleFlatMapper.

Comment: @localhost: Good luck with that *"some reason"*. I don't know how to do these things with SimpleFlatMapper, which is a third party library. I really recommend reviewing that *"some reason"* and upgrading to the above approach. But maybe someone else can answer your original question about `SimpleFlatMapper